# Is there a difference between "illegal activity" and "criminal activity"?

Tags: contract-law, legal-terms

What is the difference in meaning and use of the phrases "illegal activity" and "criminal activity"? Is one broader than the other?

Answer (score 4):

Illegal activity is activity that contravenes the law.

Criminal activity is illegal activity that is also a crime. What constitutes a crime is usually detailed in a criminal code in each jurisdiction but can derive from common law crimes like murder, arson, rape etc. A crime is an offense against society and is generally prosecuted by the state.

For example (may vary by jurisdiction):

- Breaking a contract - illegal
- Stopping in a No Stopping zone - illegal
- Negligently polluting the environment - illegal
- Breaking someone's arm - crime
- Deliberately ramming someone with your car - crime
- Recklessly polluting the environment - crime

Comment: @Philipp what is a crime?